# how to release memory for wcf ria service call?

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have following code for a silverlight app wit wcf ria service in a static method:

```
public static void mymethod(){
DomainContext context = new DomainContext();
var q = context.GetMyEntitiesQuery().Where(x => x.Name == name );
context.Load<MyEntity>(q, LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,
  (p) =>
  {
  if (!p.HasError)
    {
     //......     
    }

  }, null);
}
```

It is working fine. but every time when I call this method, the memory will be increased about 3M for browser process and it's never released.

How to release the memory for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should as few instances of DomainContext as possible. Perhaps pass the context from the caller

```
Thing.mymethod(context);
```

or keep a static instance

```
public static class Thing
{
    DomainContext _Context = new DomainContext();

    public static void mymethod()
    {
        var q = _context.GetMyEntitiesQuery().Where(x => x.Name == name );
        ...
    }
}
```

Every instance you create is probably sticking around and creating that memory leak.

Comment: I completely agree with Ed, also, consider that WCF Ria Services hevaily rely on the concept of "Context", while in your code you're using just like a plain wcf proxy